# 'dotnet ef database update' command gives error: Host 'host.docker.internal' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, docker, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

Hi StackOverflow Community,

I have a code first application in .netcore 3.0 that connects to SQL Server in the back-end.
I am trying to migrate my existing SQL Server Database to MySQL.

**dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreation** command worked well.

However,

**dotnet ef database update** command gives an error:

Can anyone explain what is going on and why **host.docker.internal** is not allowed to connect?

[This is the Migrations reference document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)
 and here is the error:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Host 'host.docker.internal' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQLDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<Exists>b__0(DateTime giveUp)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext c, TState s)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQLDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQLDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Host 'host.docker.internal' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Comment: One more thing, I am not using Docker, and still it shows that error message, so not sure where it is picking it from.

Answer (score 2):

It's look like you try to use a MySQL user that is not allowed to connect from this hostname.

On MySQL, when you create a user, you specify a username and a host `user@host`.
If the hostname doesn't fit, the user can't connect to the server.

If you want a user that could connect from anywhere, you need to use the hostname `%` like `'username'@'%'`.

For more information, you can read the MySQL doc about account names: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-names.html

You can check the user list with this query:

```
mysql> select Host, User from mysql.user;
+-----------+---------------+
| Host      | User          |
+-----------+---------------+
| localhost | mysql.session |
| localhost | mysql.sys     |
| localhost | root          |
| %         | julien        |
+-----------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

On this example, the user `julien` can connect to MySQL from anywhere but user `root` could connect to mysql only from localhost.

In your case, the connection come from `host.docker.internal`, the hostname of your host from the point of vue of the MySQL container. The MySQL container doesn't have the some `localhost` than your host or than an another container.

If the user used for the connection is not authorized in MySQL to connect from `host.docker.internal` or from anywhere, MySQL will reject the connection with the error `Host 'host.docker.internal' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`

Comment: do you have a docker specific example?
The link that you shared does not specify about docker host.

Comment: The problem is not related to docker, it's how MySQL works. How did you create the MySQL user used by your application?

Comment: I am trying to migrate from SQL to MySQL and the architecture of my application is code first (So DB is updated as per Model objects in code).

So I have to pass connection string to the object of DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>. This I am pulling from config file and my connection string looks like this:

"server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;database=mydb;user=sa;password=passwordxyz"

Also, for the migration, I just created empty mydb database using MySQL workbench in the beginning.

Comment: You try to connect to MySQL from somewhere else than the same host as MySQL. The user you use is not allowed to connect from this host `host.docker.internal`. Can you check the user you use, what is it's hostname in MySQL ? You can list all the user with this query: `SELECT Host, User FROM mysq.user;` If the user you use doesn't have `%` as host, it will be available to log only from the hostname specified.